# Is there any drawing functionality on Azure Maps?

Tags: javascript, geojson, azure-maps

I'm working with Azure Maps and have a very basic idea of it's WEB sdk. What I want to know is- is there a drawing feature in The Azure Maps SDK that a user may use to draw on the map and return a geoJSON based on it. This functionality is identical to the one provided on geojson.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is! Please check out [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Drawing%20Tools%20Module/Get%20drawn%20shapes%20from%20drawing%20manager.html), and live demo [here](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Drawing%20Tools%20Module/Get%20drawn%20shapes%20from%20drawing%20manager.html).

[image]